# Jquery animate indefinitely

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Have read a lot of articles, but can't make animate function to run indefinitely. Help me please.

```
$.move = function(object, direction) {
    $(object).animate({
        backgroundPosition:'('+ direction +' -15000px)'
    }, 20000, 'linear', function(){ $.move(object, direction) } );
};
```

Comment: Did you try `$.move(this,direction)`?

Comment: Apparently there are issues with animating the backgroundPosition rule. You might want to use a setInterval and set the css instead.

Comment: `setInterval(function(){
   $('#stars1').animate({
    'background-position-x': '-2000px',
    'background-position-y': '-15000px'
   }, 200, 'linear');
  }, 1);`
Don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have done!

```
        $('#stars1').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
        $('#stars2').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});

        function move(object, direction){
            $(object).animate({backgroundPosition:'('+ direction +' -15000px)'}, 20000, 'linear', function(){$(object).css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'}); move(object, direction); });
        };

        move($("#stars1"), '-2000px');
        move($("#stars2"), '+2000px');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use `$.move` as opposed to `.move`, but you can create jQuery methods that act on selectors:

```
$.fn.move = function() {
    $(this).animate({...}, function(){ $(this).move() } );
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mG6W4/

Comment: @Saa67 what do you mean by indefinitely?  As far as I can tell my demo does.  What browser?

Comment: any browser. ie, opera, ff, chrome

Comment: @Saa67 when does it stop moving?

Comment: @Saa67 what is supposed to move forever that doesn't?

Comment: exactly! stars must move forever.

Comment: @Saa67 I was asking *what* needs to move forever.  Now I know you mean the stars.  I don't know why they stop moving after a while; are you sure there is no other javascript going on on the page that could interrupt that?

Comment: I have tried to remove all scripts, that are not connected with stars - same trouble.